# stop script execution for n seconds

Tags: python

In my case, the method sleep() (time module) pause the script execution.
(The Scipt is internaly full compiled and simply waiting for n seconds till continue).

I'm searching for a "Stopping Script-execution" for n-seconds.

For example, I read rfid-Tags via uart and count cnt one up.
I hold the RFID-Tag for 2 Seconds on the reader, in this 2 seconds the reader process the tag 4 times.

Therefore my result is:

```
1

-wating 10 seconds-

2

-wating 10 seconds-

3

-wating 10 seconds-

4

-wating 10 seconds-
```

How can I tell the Script, to **stop** the Execution for 10 seconds after reading a tag? I don't want to process the same tag multiple times. 
It should not be possible to scan the tag multiple times in this 10 seconds.

python code

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 2400, timeout=1)
cnt=0
while True:
    string = ser.read(12) 

    if len(string) == 0:
        continue
    else:

        cnt=cnt+1
        print cnt
        time.sleep(10)
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you held the tag against the reader for 2 seconds and in that time it waited 10 seconds 4 times. Please clarify. Anyway, what about storing the strings you get in a set? Or are duplicates possible?

Comment: To me it seems your problem is not with your loop being blocked (for whatever amount of time), but the reader actually returning the same 12 bytes of data 4 times in a row. That would indicate that you should include some logic that keeps track of the last tag, and only counts a tag if it's different from the last one seen.

Comment: Or in other words: What happens if you hold the tag to the reader, remove it, hold it to the reader again, etc.. a whole bunch of times, and then `read()` all the available bytes from the device? From what you describe, I'd expect  several repetitions of the same tag ID because it was scanned multiple times.

Comment: thank you guys, i found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

pySerial is buffered (data sent while sleeping is stored), therefore a time.sleep() has no effect on Serial.read().

Use flush() or flushInput to clear the buffer.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 2400, timeout=1)
cnt=0
while True:

    ser.flushInput()   ## clear buffer

    string = ser.read(12) 

    if len(string) == 0:
        continue
    else:

        cnt=cnt+1
        print cnt 
        ser.flushInput()  # clear buffer
        time.sleep(10)
```